# Wrapping meteor.js handlebars templates in coffeescript classes

Tags: coffeescript, meteor, handlebars.js

I'm totally digging on meteor, but I'm stuck trying to cut down on the global-ness of the examples and add a dash of OOP.

Currently, my code looks like this:

```
# View for Search Form
form = Template.SearchForm  
form.events =
  'submit #search_form' : query_submitted
  'click #load_more' : -> Songs.get_next_page()
  'focus #query' : clear_query_field

form.page = -> Songs.page
form.total_pages = -> Songs.total_pages
```

But, a la spine or backbone, what I'd really like to have is something like this:

```
class SearchForm extends Template.SearchForm
  events:
    'submit #search_form' : query_submitted
    'click #load_more' : -> Songs.get_next_page()
    'focus #query' : clear_query_field


  page : -> Songs.page
  total_pages : -> Songs.page

  # etc etc

form = new SearchForm
```

What's the right way to wrap a handlebars template in meteor?

I've managed to wrap Meteor.Collection, but because handlebars names the object after the template, I'm not sure the right way to do it for the Template.

**UPDATED**

@greg pointed out that you can use _.extend to add the properties.  That works, but what if I want to fold the event handler methods 'query_submitted' and 'clear_query_field' into the class?  Something like this:

```
_.extend Template.SearchForm,
  events :
    'submit #search_form' : @query_submitted
    'click #load_more' : -> Songs.get_next_page()
    'focus #query' : @clear_query_field

  page : -> Songs.page
  total_pages : -> Songs.total_pages

  clear_query_field : (event) ->
    console.log 'focus'

  query_submitted : (event) ->
    event.preventDefault()
    Songs.clear()
    Songs.query = $('#query')[0].value 
    Songs.search()
```

Doesn't quite work.  The event handlers aren't being called properly and I get errors in the console like:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Window] has no method
>   'query_submitted'

Similarly,

```
events :
    'submit #search_form' : (e) -> @query_submitted(e)
```

Gives:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'call' of undefined

So what's missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Meteor comes with underscore so you could:

```
_.extend Template.SearchForm,
  events:
    'submit #search_form' : query_submitted
    'click #load_more' : -> Songs.get_next_page()
    'focus #query' : clear_query_field

  page: -> Songs.page

  total_pages: -> Songs.page
```

Comment: Thanks, @greg!  I found the _.extend solution, but I'm still having trouble extending to include the event handler functions.  I've updated the question, would you take a look?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried replacing @ with Template.Searchform. in your event bindings?

Comment: This works if you first extend with the handlers, then extend again with the event definitions:

`_.extend Template.SearchForm,
  clear_query_field : (event) -> yadda yadda

_.extend Template.SearchForm
  events:
    'focus #query' : clear_query_field
...
`

Comment: @ScottSimon could you provide an update in your original question, regarding your findings. tks